# How to package closed-source framework as CocoaPod

Tags: cocoapods

I have a iOS framework for which I don't have the source and the authors have not provided a podspec for it. I'm already using CocoaPods for multiple other libs and would love to keep this one along with them.

Is it possible to create a `podspec` file that will simply reuse the existing framework binary?

I have:

```
xxx.embeddedframework/
   xxx.framework
   Resources/
       yyyy.momd
```

I know all the details like what system frameworks it depends on.

I suspect `vendored_frameworks` may be an answer, but I'm not sure how to write one. For example, `s.source` is mandatory parameter and I don't have any source files so `pod spec lint` fails.

Comment: I'm actually currently trying to do this myself. I came across http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-a-third-party-framework-in-a-private-cocoapod which seems like it might be a good starting point for us

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Not yet, did not have more time to spend on it. I integrated the framework directly for now. Hopefully in few weeks I will have more time to investigate this